# Expression.Like in C#

Tags: c#, expression-trees, sql-like

**eg: x=> x.Name = "g"**

I have code block like this

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SearchExpression()
{
    var c = new ConstantExpression[_paramList.Count];
    var b = new BinaryExpression[_paramList.Count];
    BinaryExpression comparisonExpression = null;

    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

    for (int i = 0; i < _paramList.Count; i++)
    {
        var value = Convert.ChangeType(_paramList[i].Item2 /*"g"*/, _paramList[i].Item3 /*System.String*/);
        c[i] = Expression.Constant(value); //"g"

        // PROBLEM IS HERE
        b[i] = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(entity, _paramList[i].Item1 /*Name*/, c[i]);
        // PROBLEM IS HERE



    }
    _paramList.Clear();
    comparisonExpression = b.Aggregate(Expression.And);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(comparisonExpression, entity);
}
```

works like charm but I need **Expression.Like** *(Like "g" not Equal "g")*

```
Expression.Like(Expression.Property(entity, _paramList[i].Item1), c[i])
```

but C# expression tree does not support Like method

**UPDATE** :

I wrote something like this :

```
Expression.Call(Expression.Property(entity, _paramList[i].Item1),
                typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains"), new Expression[] { c[i] });
```

but I need BinaryExpression not MethodCallExpression

Comment: I think you need to inject a method invocation to string.Contains. `Expression.Like` is not out of the box available as an expression.

Comment: @Adrian Wragg, In ExpressionTree not strings !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user3432343 *Possible*. If you're saying it's not, I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Marc Gravell did something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/958098/)

Comment: @chridam , Yes i saw that but I cant use it in my code block :(

Comment: Why do you need a `BinaryExpression` as opposed to a `MethodCallExpression`?

Comment: @usr, please see my post better "comparisonExpression = b.Aggregate(Expression.And)" I need aggregation for multiple expresstions

Comment: I saw that. Any `Expression` should do. Don't you think?

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` has the `Like` operator defined in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator.LikeString()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make your code work by adding an equals expression over the method call, like so:

```
    b[i] = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Call(Expression.Property(entity, _paramList[i].Item1),
        typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains"), 
          new Expression[] {c[i]}), Expression.Constant(true));
```

In pseudo code this reads as:

```
b[i] = entity => entity.someProperty.Contains(c[i]) == true;
```

Which will return a binary expression for you.

Answer (score 5):

This answer does not consider your array and the 'and' aggregation, but this should be considered as a separate issue.

Consider this class:

```
class MyEntity { string Name { get; set; } }
```

We want to query:

```
select ... from MyEntity where Name like '%query%';
```

The following method is a general implementation of the above query pattern:

```
static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Like<TEntity>(string propertyName, string queryText)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntity), "entity");
    var getter = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    //ToString is not supported in Linq-To-Entities, throw an exception if the property is not a string.
    if (getter.Type != typeof (string))
        throw new ArgumentException("Property must be a string");
    //string.Contains with string parameter.
    var stringContainsMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof (string)});
    var containsCall = Expression.Call(getter, stringContainsMethod,
        Expression.Constant(queryText, typeof (string)));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsCall, parameter);
}
```

If you want to have a pattern of `query%` or `%query` you can use `string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Also, you can share the parameter across multiple calls if you adjust the signature.

The current implementation throws an exception if the data type of the property is not a string. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/668272 for converting numbers to strings.

Comment: That last statement is not true anymore as of EF 6.1. I wrote the contrib for it :).. so you can concat strings and primitives and also call .ToString() in non strings..

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in a scripting language I wrote, which allows you to say things like `name like 'bob%'`. The trick is that you need to map it to a method call which takes the value and regular expression and call this from within the `Expression`.

If you take a look at the [LikeEvaluator](https://github.com/foxesknow/cosmo/blob/master/CSharp/Source/Arrow/Arrow.Scripting.Wire/LikeEvaluator.cs) class in my **Wire** scripting language you'll see how I did it:

```
static class LikeEvaluator
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ApplyLikeMethodInfo=typeof(LikeEvaluator).GetMethod("ApplyLike");
    private static readonly MethodInfo ApplyLikeNoCaseMethodInfo=typeof(LikeEvaluator).GetMethod("ApplyLikeNoCase");

    public static Expression Like(CaseMode caseMode, Expression lhs, Expression pattern)
    {
        Expression x=null;

        if(caseMode==CaseMode.Sensitive)
        {
            x=Expression.Call(ApplyLikeMethodInfo,lhs,pattern);
        }
        else
        {
            x=Expression.Call(ApplyLikeNoCaseMethodInfo,lhs,pattern);
        }

        return x;
    }

    public static bool ApplyLike(string text, string likePattern)
    {
        string pattern=PatternToRegex(likePattern);
        return Regex.IsMatch(text,pattern,RegexOptions.None);
    }

    public static bool ApplyLikeNoCase(string text, string likePattern)
    {
        string pattern=PatternToRegex(likePattern);
        return Regex.IsMatch(text,pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    public static string PatternToRegex(string pattern)
    {
        pattern=Regex.Escape(pattern);
        pattern=pattern.Replace("%",@".*");
        pattern=string.Format("^{0}$",pattern);

        return pattern;
    }
}
```